# Python: getting an error for function, Unindented error

Tags: python, indentation, python-3.1

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to make my string change 'abc' to 'def' and in short I keep getting,`"unindented does not match any other indentation level."` Therefore, this means what is wrong with my function?

```
def changes(x):

   if 'a' in sent:
       x=sent.replace('a','d')

    if 'b' in x:
        y=x.replace('b','e')

    if 'c' in y:
        z=y.replace('c','f')
    print(z)

sent=print(input('Enter a sentence:'))

changes(x)
```

Comment: It's an indentation problem, the first if-block seems to have one less space than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your indentation. You cannot write anything anywhere like in other languages.

Read this [short guide.](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3)

Answer (score 0):

I have had, and still have, lots of these errors. What I found really useful is to turn on so I can see invisibles or whitespace. When copying fragments on code from the web, or changing between using the spacebar and the tabulator for creating indentation this can create problems with indentation

Check the if 'a' in sent, and the line below. Seems to use fewer spaces than the subsequent cases.